# Has anyone worked with Rijndael encryption on Flutter? How to encrypt with Rijndael?

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, rijndael

I am using the encrypt Flutter package. I wrote the code below to encrypt data. But I could not find the expected result.

```
  String encrypterAESdata({String? data}){ 
    final key = Key.fromUtf8(aesKey);
    final iv = IV.fromUtf8(aesKey);
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: "PKCS7" ));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(data!, iv: iv);
    return encrypted.base64;
  }
```

Test Data:

```
{
  "remittanceNoPrefix": "IT",
  "adjustedDCAmount": 0,
  "beneAccNo": "01912163589",
  "benePhone": "01912163589",
  "beneAccTypeID": 199,
  "beneAmount": "4900",
  "beneBankName": "BKASH (MOBILE ACCOUNT)",
  "beneBankBranchID": 31637,
  "beneBankID": 1135,
  "beneBranchName": "BKASH (ANY AGENT POINT)",
  "beneBrnAddress": "ANYWHERE",
  "beneCountryID": 23,
  "beneCurrencyID": 15,
  "beneDocID": null,
  "beneDocNo": "",
  "beneficiaryID": 497656,
  "beneficiarySurname": "TEST",
  "beneficiaryName": "TEST",
  "relationID": null,
  "benePayeeModeID": 11,
  "subCompanyBranchID": 151886,
  "companyID": 76,
  "subCompanyID": 367,
  "debitCardID": null,
  "discountedComm": 0,
  "encashedPoint": 0,
  "encashedPointAmount": 0,
  "equiAmount": 50,
  "ofrdAmount": 50,
  "equiCommission": 3,
  "ofrdCommission": 3,
  "taxAmount": 0,
  "cardCharge": 0,
  "instrumentDetail": "",
  "instrumentTypeID": "120",
  "maturityDate": "2019-02-14T00:00:00.000Z",
  "issueDate": "2019-02-14T00:00:00.000Z",
  "othrRcvdAmount": 0,
  "othrRcvdCommission": 0,
  "pDRate": 98,
  "purposeDetail": "FAMILY HELP",
  "purposeID": 2,
  "aMLRemBhvClsID": null,
  "aMLRemBhvClsValue": 0,
  "aMLOpVoteClsID": null,
  "aMLOpVoteClsValue": 0,
  "aMLCoopClsID": null,
  "aMLCoopClsValue": 0,
  "aMLOpTypeClsID": null,
  "aMLOpTypeClsValue": 0,
  "fldPsfx": "",
  "cdType": "BNKXFR",
  "cdNo": "",
  "cdExp": "",
  "cdSecCode": ""
}
```

Expected Result:

```
/qDmHF87PF/E6Bmwiot9roUrXwEvykmHzCLMbKq2YnVUuHDGqXqMWlJ8ZhCzMBcqppkpvjY6NkN8bUUp0fYZz1Pl6I5E/qtIaxbvrMOU+wRDpLvV1Ymd+o+J1fe0PLAmC5SUXsj1MyRCPG0LJ1cRjHR7F4HnWJZoGOCmeh3nZrzGSkdVQ3Xya8c8eK0RiAkcgUABpwptY77yknR1WNEV6HoOnOxdPt6vo/D0oba17jp5coonFCcVUsmZ3PacRmCzVuhbvqaFJgCoykBZOkzsSUgl792F1QP9995q/S/hmFJZv2JHyNKeOGLJ55uMSVHYTPOvqgAn7VZ2CkiTBQSaDJpWzLF/3HpQR9jjgY3n5cOGqJyPbWiLz0N4jWeOJ6TUnyBd8K5PhtOY8C+uh5GkeyAWrieEFbX1Q5pytaUKcqDBTOWjF3945ImVSoviZYHDaPgJ8f/1V3FuAdH3VM+zpzlBAmVwtcjfZZzfzdDSOUgYeU98P+JjWfqX8bQu5vXBSCnkMqEENyM85z9ISoi+oYKnsYNt6sPKOf2lVIxj+9vA9G1+fCfNTH1a7Tg2yszSHA3yTNy1QLTqQY9fCS0A/vIgJPjHYJPjjLNK4CA0L1mZje8Rkh9eha8BD61/6YPAJFAfiU6eNK8uC5gToMSdOTt2auj2i3yuPx8sLyTBe8MOI3TOCoE/xC2yqCUxuUqH1ppn2TKlNjULy2ChiJG5o3cTC6b7trAaNzn+B8220TkaM1+k5RDvELd6+GcxdteO43oECs2eoXYF28z+V/kGHAhQeBBMKEF5sAaD3Qnq+IX4uHOjc6ngu41IbKnvrMaDL+o1qjfrLILQAPgYYHSzzp/C7Ov1Yzym0bR8dp7g+ATFj+1sgNOQWyzVr7v74stncu0aREBPJFTn1SkoajFJ2XD40+65IHw6ZKxfeXT2ArKueZrXPFYI/j5FW1jVfyM66FW6prmJ33PfadQ1OLMRS84FKhv3xfXP20hca/mMDXWzVOfhMDhPQRx0txL6Qh6AqS984UgM6CTcWIGL7UC7UMDtEYrcsLOw0y7LR0vD0acH+d4NESC7AzyDaN4//otzaYyOeNvYCraDWx0DpPyJCQfQSQKctzELHWgcb8hHgMup42ewu4+cMml42eTwVjrbKAYcSTYeimb0aVa9LlObOoUBFBrudzhhyXueYd1+RK83k8BuCyxo9jsk7oDlsngm4j8HdOvp2TJm4gFs1wTDR4lQmuqVNMdorJT6iO7f/tEuOMTb6lXueM7XWDlQ9vbUYDlG8py9K3Tfd6cPny2L7uzdCk2OnnmEpYmVM3nzhgY1wYz/TwS3sWAYriRDJ1WhXKoCWC7iXn+rKq1QwctxatFiz14zYtU41ucXFM0uiU76jPYQ8q3UsGHMvoL7pbAii4qW05QEcDuGjI/kJgtTf8KWZz+tk7ii3nnh+nrh//1hiC8sC1GJ7/PIdvPj4yXWv0wG8XONfl43MIRTD1n43ePkNQaYyeGFmcZc+BJjPTZ6Z7KZjACbaeS8YZlAE8EAOVGNzq4oZFpFt/+VJcMIa17LtCrjTqcDuDFggjO633Z3ISLnAZJeYoaXtFWaehdZVCimTh0xCnON63jlmyrZoL38cCqFfBiEcJ4O04Pfqob6FEhgTEk4vhQLV7n/O4LhsR9yyfnipY2IrZHVOIGYDJfnw3D4NrpKjBRxq2q/ihTLYzQCpmyXaFVNmgIsv37fdgk2TYZ6leyVs+jDdUwogluqzbTEGOOqK4ZqvLgntEYEFjGEP4Ztjwu48BuLvsT2vH/zuKMW5L0WtZYn6Ytq2sFDJ2aoFSWvUwnz4w5lrrD1dmOOJJGpnn3aNAWcwx5DZk7tCFOp0D6zGtajLM7pMA==
```

Key:

```
**********
```

IV:

```
*********
```

Comment: Post test data: plaintext, key, IV and expected and current ciphertext.

Comment: I provided test data: plaintext, key, IV

Comment: On my machine, the code for the posted data returns exactly the ciphertext you posted. You may have formatted the plaintext differently (line breaks, blanks, etc.). Post the ciphertext you *currently* receive, then it may be possible to determine why the ciphertexts differ.

Comment: As a sidenote, you should use a KDF to derive a real key from the password, and your IV certainly should not be the same as the key even if the IV is not part of the output (which is unclear in the present case). At best you have CWE-329, at worst you ship the key with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never find the 'wrapper' packages around `pointcastle` useful. They just add layers of obfuscation in the name of adding 'simplicity'. It's often easier to just use the underlying package directly.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';

void main() {
  final k = 'Nec_uK_2@!6_CebD';
  final key = utf8.encode(k) as Uint8List;
  final iv = key;

  print(key);

  final cipher = PaddedBlockCipherImpl(
    PKCS7Padding(),
    CBCBlockCipher(AESEngine()),
  )..init(
      true,
      PaddedBlockCipherParameters(
        ParametersWithIV(KeyParameter(key), iv),
        null,
      ),
    );

  final data = utf8.encode(pt) as Uint8List;
  final ct = cipher.process(data);

  print(data.length);
  print(ct.length);
  print(base64.encode(ct));
}

final pt = '''{
  "remittanceNoPrefix": "IT",
  "adjustedDCAmount": 0,
  ...
  "cdExp": "",
  "cdSecCode": ""
}''';
```

Answer (score -2):

easy peasy

```
import 'package:cryptography/cryptography.dart';

String s = "i want to encrypt this init";

String key = 'AA­èìýUn}a…ópŒ¹%J'yL4ßK,£½';

List<int> listint= utf8.encode(s);

Uint8List listUint= Uint8List.fromList(key.codeUnits);


AesGcm algorithm = AesGcm.with256bits();

SecretKey secretKey = await algorithm.newSecretKeyFromBytes(listUint);


    SecretBox secretBox = await algorithm.encrypt(
      listint,
      secretKey: secretKey,
    );

    print('Nonce: ${secretBox.nonce}');
    print('Ciphertext: ${secretBox.cipherText}');
    print('MAC: ${secretBox.mac.bytes}');


    Uint8List listEncryptedUint = secretBox.concatenation();
    print('this is the encrypted payload init: '+listEncryptedUint .toString());
```