# I want to decrypt and enccrypt the data in flutter

Tags: java, flutter, dart, encryption, aes

I want to encrypt the data in flutter using the AES cbc-128 algorithm. below is the java code for that i want to achieve the same functionality as below but in dart. i have tried

> [cryptography](https://pub.dev/packages/cryptography)

dependency  in flutter but the problem with that is that i want to use my own key in the algorithm as below in the java code. if you know any method for achieving this please let me know.

```
public static String Decrypt(String text, String key) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
    byte[] b = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    int len = b.length;
    if (len > keyBytes.length)
        len = keyBytes.length;
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(decoder.decodeBuffer(text));
    return new String(results, "UTF-8");
}

public static String Encrypt(String text, String key) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
    byte[] b = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    int len = b.length;
    if (len > keyBytes.length)
        len = keyBytes.length;
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
    byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    return encoder.encode(results);
}
```

**Test Case**

For the following input

> plainText="This is plain text";

> key="sahtojetrout2";

i want the encrypted result to be

> encryptedText="8FmSMnDsFJVyNUXunhJLSmhFnRq89fl5DyTp0wdYfgk=";

which [Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco) has written in an online editor you can check out that here [Java Code](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/t0G). In flutter i have tried the program given at the [Flutter site](https://pub.dev/documentation/cryptography/latest/cryptography/AesCbc-class.html)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72604034/has-anyone-worked-with-rijndael-encryption-on-flutter-how-to-encrypt-with-rijnd/72605182#72605182

Comment: *...but the problem with that is that i want to use my own key...*: Why shouldn't this work (see [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/cryptography/latest/cryptography/SecretKey/SecretKey.html))? Post your most recent Dart code. Note that the Java code uses the key as IV, which is insecure. You should tweak the Java code before porting.

Comment: @Topaco i don't know whether it is secure or not but it is the client requirement. He had already created the web, back-end and API for the project i only have to target that API but before that i have to encrypt the data which then will be send to the back-end through API. The encryption will be done same as the java coding is doing it.  This is the test case which is encrypt using java i want to achieve the similar result in flutter plainText="This is plain text", key="sahtojetrout2", the encrypted result will be "adqrKxlkPf22N10Z/pzT0yG0JTa+ECwxnEfTjREM/Lk="

Comment: Your test data is inconsistent. The Java code does not provide the posted ciphertext for the posted plaintext and key. Convince yourself online here: https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/t0G. Please post consistent data and your most recent Dart code as a starting point! Also, edit the question and post the data there (code/data in comments is hard to read).

Comment: @Topaco sorry i pasted the wrong result. and i want the same result as this program is displaying with that text and key https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/t0G. how can it be possible

Comment: Since SO is not a code writing service, please post your most recent Dart code as starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do AES CBC-128 encryption in flutter with the help of [**crypt**](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) library. It supports the AES cbc encryption. The following sample code accepts key-string and plain-text as arguments and encrypts it as you have mentioned. You can pass your own key here. For AES-128, you need 128 bit key or 16 character string.

```dart
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

void main() {
    final key = "Your16CharacterK";
    final plainText = "lorem ipsum example example";
    Encrypted encrypted = encrypt(key, plainText);
    String decryptedText = decrypt(key, encrypted);
    print(decryptedText);
}

String decrypt(String keyString, Encrypted encryptedData) {
    final key = Key.fromUtf8(keyString);
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
    final initVector = IV.fromUtf8(keyString.substring(0, 16));
    return encrypter.decrypt(encryptedData, iv: initVector);
}

Encrypted encrypt(String keyString, String plainText) {
    final key = Key.fromUtf8(keyString);
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
    final initVector = IV.fromUtf8(keyString.substring(0, 16));
    Encrypted encryptedData = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: initVector);
    return encryptedData;
}
```

In the above example, the IV is created from the key itself to keep the code easy to read. Use random data for IV for better security. Referred article for [flutter encryption](https://genuinecoder.com/encryption-and-decryption-in-flutter/).